# Check if a parameter of a function is a function

Tags: function, parameters, julia, singleton, typeof

I have a function:

```
function f(a)
   do something that depends on a
end
```

which behaviour depends on the parameter `a`. This can be a string, an int or a function itself. For this, I want to check if the parameter is a function itself.

```
function f(a)
   if typeof(a) == int
      ...
   end
   ...
end
```

I tried to use `typeof(a)`. If `a` is a function, I get :

```
typeof(a) (singleton type of function a, subtype of Function)
```

but if I then use:

```
typeof(a) == Function
```

it is `false`.

Comment: Caveat: not every callable value `isa Function`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `isa()` for this. A simple example:

```
julia> f(x) = x
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> isa(f, Function)
true
```

`isa` can also be used as an infix operator:

```
julia> f isa Function
true
```

Answer (score 6):

You might also consider using Julia's Multiple Dispatch feature:

```
function f(x::Function)
  # do something with a Function
end

funcion f(x::Int)
  # do something with an Int
end
```

instead of using conditions inside the function.

This has the benefit of being faster if the compiler can do the type inference during compile-time and being more Julian.